# How to plot in the complex plane?

Tags: plotting, complex

I am new to *Mathematica* and I would like to ask how to plot in the complex plane in general. Also, as an example, how do you plot $e^{i\theta}$ in *Mathematica*? In physics the function $e^{i\theta}$ is called the wavefunction for a free particle so I also like to plot it in Mathematica as a free particle. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please search this site for similar questions; you could start from [this search](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=plot+complex+is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3Ayes).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, I think I stated the problem incompletely. In physics the function $e^{i\theta}$ is called the wavefunction for a free particle. So I also like to plot it in Mathematica as a free particle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon MarcoB's suggestion:

```
complex[θ_] = Exp[I θ];
ListPlot[Table[ReIm@complex@θ, {θ, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, Joined -> True]
```

**Example**

```
complex[θ_] = Log@θ Exp[I θ];
ListPlot[Table[ReIm@complex@θ, {θ, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Consider using [`ReIm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html) instead of constructing the list of real, imaginary parts yourself. This would work just fine as well: `Plot[ReIm@complex@θ, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}]`.

Answer (score 6):

A compact approach is

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[Log[θ] Exp[I θ]], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

producing the same curve that appears in the answer by thedude.  It works for any complex function of a single real variable.

Appropriate to the season, a cartiod can be plotted by

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[I(Exp[I θ] + 1)^2], {θ, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]